# Como validar si un table (tbody) tiene información sin contar el encabezado

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Tengo un tbody que voy llenandolo de informacion, dependiendo de un filtro y un mapeo realizado a "data"(este data es pasado por parametro desde otro componente), en ciertos casos hay información y en otros no(depende del filtro del año y mes en el cual se encuentra), como puedo validar si tengo información o filas( adicionales a la cabecera) en dicho table, adjunto unas fotos de la forma visual y el codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
const TableConsol = ({ confirmDelete, data, names, anio, mes, setApoyo }) => {
  
    const copiarDatos = async (e) => {
    if (mes == "enero") {
      data
        .filter((dat) => dat.mes == "diciembre" && dat.anio == anio - 1)
        .map((da) =>
          setApoyo((prevState) => [
            ...prevState,
            {
              anio: anio,
              mes: mes,
              roomName: da.roomName,
              dni: da.dni,
              lastName: da.lastName,
              name: da.name,
              montoPagado: 0,
              phone: da.phone,
              price: da.price,
            },
          ])
        );

      console.log("ingresamos a enero");
    } else {
      console.log("ingresamos a otro mes que no es enero");

      const meses = [
        "diciembre",            
        "noviembre",
      ];
      let mesAnterior;

      if (mes === "diciembre") {
        // si el caso es diciembre, entonces el anterior es noviembre.
        mesAnterior = "noviembre";
      } else {
        // en cualquier otro caso, el mes anterior es el que se encuentra una posición antes en el arreglo de meses.
        const indiceMesActual = meses.indexOf(mes);
        mesAnterior = meses[indiceMesActual - 1];
      }

      data
        .filter((dat) => dat.mes == mesAnterior && dat.anio == anio)
        .map((da) =>
          setApoyo((prevState) => [
            ...prevState,
            {
              anio: anio,
              mes: mes,
              roomName: da.roomName,                 
            },
          ])
        );
    }
  };
  const storeCopiarDatos = async (e) => {
    
    console.log(e);

    setApoyo([]);
    copiarDatos();
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <hr />
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <div className="d-grid gap-2">
              <Link
                to="/createconsolidado"
                state={{ names: names, anio: anio, mes: mes }}
                className="btn btn-secondary mt-2 mb-2"
              >
                CREATE
              </Link>
            </div>

            <table className="table table-dark table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>CUARTO</th>
                  <th>DNI</th>                      
                  <th>ACCION</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {data
                  .filter((dat) => dat.mes === mes && dat.anio === anio)
                  .map((dat) => (
                    
                    <tr key={dat.id} >
                      <td>{dat.roomName}</td>
                      <td>{dat.dni}</td>             
                      <td>
                        <Link
                          to={`/edit/${dat.id}`}
                          state={{ names: names }}
                          className="btn btn-light"
                        >
                          <i className="fa-solid fa-pencil"></i>
                        </Link>
                        <button
                          onClick={() => {
                            confirmDelete(dat.id);
                          }}
                          className="btn btn-danger"
                        >
                          <i className="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
                        </button>
                      </td>                        

                    </tr>
                  ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>

            <button onClick={storeCopiarDatos} value={mes}>
              Test
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default TableConsol;
```

En caso se necesite información no duden en comentar para poder actualizar el post por favor

Comment: lo pondre como comentario por que no estoy seguro si es lo que buscas, pero si tienes que las filas se generan en base a la variable data, si el data.length es == 0 es porque no hay ninguna fila en la tabla

Comment: tu comentario fue la solución jajaja, si lo pones como respuesta lo marco, muchas gracias!

Comment: ya lo agregue como solucion, de nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si tienes que las filas se generan en base a la variable data, si el data.length es == 0 es porque no hay ninguna fila en la tabla.